# Display community wiki posts differently on various listings

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Use some visual distinction on community wiki post display in various SO listings (on user page and on the main listings), for example: different color, [CW] displayed after the title or auto-add community-wiki tag to it?

Comment: Bounty: design for a good graphical distinction example

Comment: I would say, status-completed, somewhere else.

Comment: I wish I could do more than 1 upvote on this... I almost posted it as a question until I seen you one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely feel that a community wiki question should be different from a regular question. The latter is usually direct and looking for 1 answer. The former is usually not worth the effort to read all the answers to before throwing in something.

Personally I don't care if the question looks different in the list view, but would appreciate if they all came with a free 6th tag of <community-wiki>, that doesn't have to show anywhere (though that would be odd) but can be filtered against so that it's not in your list view.

Comment: Thanks for the support. It seems I have to do it in my own frontend one day.

Answer (score 1):

A visual distinction would be helpful at the profile screen, you easily see which posts are CW, and which are not. Otherwise, you have to go to the post itself to learn its status.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that was what the [subjective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subjective) tag was for...

Only kidding...I like this idea. Maybe give it a light gray tint on the background so we know it's wiki. We probably don't have to add yet another tag to it.

Comment: Cummunity Wiki != Subjective

Comment: For CW distinction you mean?

Answer (score 0):

For the whole graphical part of how it would be displayed, I suggest displaying them with a blue background similar to how you display owner's answers. Very simple, and conveys a clear uniqueness.